# take 1 list of lists and make x number of squares where x is the size of the list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So Im working on a project for a class, an it calls to make a List where you have lets say a 9x9 square, and create a new list where it would be 9 sets of 3x3.

example list:

```
L = [[5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2],
     [6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8],
     [1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7],
     [8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3],
     [4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1],
     [7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6],
     [9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4],
     [2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5],
     [3,4,5,2,8,6,1,7,9]]
```

so I want my new list to be:

```
newL = [[5,3,4,6,7,2,1,9,8],
       ....
```

I hope you can see the pattern.

After 5 hours, I was basically able to recreate the list with list comprehension:

```
List = [[row[col] for col in range(len(list1))] for row in  list1]
```

then the closest I was able to get is:

```
List = [[row[col] for col in range(int(sqrtofsize)] for row in  list1]
```

where it would print out the first 3 of each element, then I though well I can create 3 separate lists, the only issue is if you have a 16x16 block it wont work.

the other issue is I cant make it subscritable.

Im sure there is information out there, though I have been looking for 5 hours and I just cant figure it out.

please ask for clarification.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use integer division and modulo:

```
newL = [[L[3*(i//3)+j//3][3*(i%3)+j%3] for j in range(9)] for i in range(9)]
```

Result:

```
[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 8]
[6, 7, 8, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 2]
[9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 5, 9, 4, 2, 6, 7, 1, 3]
[7, 6, 1, 8, 5, 3, 9, 2, 4]
[4, 2, 3, 7, 9, 1, 8, 5, 6]
[9, 6, 1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 3, 7, 4, 1, 9, 2, 8, 6]
[2, 8, 4, 6, 3, 5, 1, 7, 9]
```

See the code in action here: http://ideone.com/XSHhLj

I'll explain the easier case of iterating on 3x3 array using one variable:

```
L = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]
iterL = [ L[i//3][i%3] for i in range(9) ]
```

Which results in:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So every increment of 3 you increase the row by one (done using `i//3`), and put the column to 0 (done using `i%3`). So when `i=4` you will point to index `1,0`.

Then use this idea, expanded to larger array. =)

To make it work with variable size (quadratic of course), just change every occurrence of `3` into the square root of the size, and `9` into the size of the list.

Comment: It depends on which version of Python you use. On my Python 2.7.2, the code above works (that's why I can print the result). You can convert `i/3` into `int(i/3)` and `j/3` into `int(j/3)` just to be sure. But I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: Yeah Im running python 3.x, and they want it, also I think because of this its not coming out right, Im going to try again.

Comment: In Python 3, you should use double slash for integer division: `i//3` and `j//3`

Comment: Still working with it. This is and extension of the first post correct?

Comment: Im getting list index out of range.

Comment: Hmm, it works in my machine. Are you putting the list you have here? I'm sure the code is correct: http://ideone.com/XSHhLj

Comment: for x in range(N):
                       for y in range(N):
                                tempList = [[ list1[row][col] for col in range(N*y, N*y+N)] for row in range(N*x, N*x+N)]
                                sqarelist = [[ tempList[N*(i//N)+j//N][N*(i%N)+j%N] for j in range(len(list1))] for i in range(len(list1)) ]

Comment: Hmm, this is not an extension of the other answer. Just use this directly. See this link: http://ideone.com/XSHhLj

Comment: Glad this helps you. Still you like the other answer better? haha

Comment: No this one is great, just new to Python thats all (going with your answer)

Answer (score 2):

```
def subsquare(L, N, x, y):
  return [ [ L[i][j] for j in range(N*y, N*y+N) ] for i in range(N*x, N*x+N) ]

N = 3

L = [[5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2],
     [6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8],
     [1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7],
     [8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3],
     [4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1],
     [7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6],
     [9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4],
     [2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5],
     [3,4,5,2,8,6,1,7,9]]

subsqaure(L, N, 0, 0)
[[5, 3, 4], [6, 7, 2], [1, 9, 8]]

for x in range(N):
   for y in range(N):
       print x, y, subsquare(L, N, x, y)


 0 0 [[5, 3, 4], [6, 7, 2], [1, 9, 8]]
 0 1 [[6, 7, 8], [1, 9, 5], [3, 4, 2]]
 0 2 [[9, 1, 2], [3, 4, 8], [5, 6, 7]]
 1 0 [[8, 5, 9], [4, 2, 6], [7, 1, 3]]
 1 1 [[7, 6, 1], [8, 5, 3], [9, 2, 4]]
 1 2 [[4, 2, 3], [7, 9, 1], [8, 5, 6]]
 2 0 [[9, 6, 1], [2, 8, 7], [3, 4, 5]]
 2 1 [[5, 3, 7], [4, 1, 9], [2, 8, 6]]
 2 2 [[2, 8, 4], [6, 3, 5], [1, 7, 9]]
```

Comment: This is great, its more or less what Im looking for, few questions though. First, I was hoping to put this in a single variable (so I can compare it. so if I just put [ [ L[i][j] for j in range(N*y, N*y+N) ] for i in range(N*x, N*x+N) ] into a variable will it give me what I want, or will that variable only hold the last set? second do you know off and a quick way to combine them so its in 9's instead of 3's? I"m going to play with this more and hopefully I can get it. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, so if you throw it into a new nested for loop it only saves the last entry. so somehow I need to create a new list with +=